# Phonegap Cordova Plugin Statusbar

Tags: cordova, phonegap

This is my first app development project. I'm using Adobe's PhoneGap Build and having a hard time with the cordova plugins.

In my config.xml file I'm placing the following code:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.4.2" />

<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#333333" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

The status bar is not updating per my preferences. What am I missing here? Am I supposed to have the plugin files in my local directory? Am I supposed to load cordova.js somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having some issues with the StatusBar plugin myself. I could resolve it by adding **platform specific styles**. I'm assuming you have installed the plugin like this:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

This will add the plugin to your `config.xml`  and also download it into your `plugins/` directory. Now you can add platform-specific preferences in your `config.xml` like so:

```
<widget>
  ...
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  ...
  <platform name="ios">
    ...
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#333333" />
    ...
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    ...
  </platform>
  ...
</widget>
```